# input type date getting date from another location

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an input of type date, on some computers it returns the date in the format  dd/MM/yyyy, but in others it returns in the format MM/DD/yyyy, I would like it to return only format dd/MM/yyyy Brazilian pattern

```
                        <div class="input-group input-group text-center input-cep w-mmd-50 input-date">
                            <input formControlName="data" type="date" min="{{today}}" class="form-control"
                            id="inputData"  >
                       </div>
```

Would there be a way to do this with just HTML or javascript or an angular pipe?
I didn't find anything about it, I searched about it and it says that it changes depending on the locale or browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value of date you get from input type="date" is in (yyyy-mm-dd) format you need to change that to your requirement. For reference you can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

```js
function myDateFormat() {

var dateControl = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');
console.log(dateControl.value);
const [year, month, day] = dateControl.value.split('-');

const result = [day, month, year].join('/');
document.getElementById("showDate").innerHTML = result;

}
```

```css
#showDate {
margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" onchange="myDateFormat()">
<div id="showDate"></div>
```

Comment: your answer is very good, but wouldn't it be possible to change the <input> ? instead of creating a new div with the correct value

Comment: If you are asking to change the format mm/dd/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy, in input itself then this is not possible because input have it's default format, it can't be changed

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date [bold face mine]

> Note: The **displayed date format** will differ from the **actual value** —
> the displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's
> browser, but the parsed value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd.

In other words, you can let browser decide formatting since this will be user dependant for international consumption.